# What can I do to get my question reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question in question is [How to role-play serious characters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73614/how-to-role-play-serious-characters)

Editing history: I acknowledge my first attempt to formulate the question was unclear and needed editing.In my view it was not because I did not have a specific thing to ask about, but rather because I did not get the point across the first time.

Since my first editing attempts in response to suggestions in the comments I decided to start from scratch and re-worded the complete question. I spent a lot of time and thought on it and think it is quite clear now. Also some people have expressed the same opinion in the comments.

**What else can I do to get the question re-opened?**

Comment: @korvinstarmast that doesn't mean "answer the questions in meta comments instead."

Comment: The question got up to 3 reopen votes so I gave it the last 2.  Enjoy.

Comment: @mxyzplk: my hero :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, you just edit and wait. It takes time for closes and it takes time for reopens.  Mentioning the revision in chat also helps.  You can post to meta as you have done, though it does junk up meta a bit when everyone escalates what they want for any given post here. I'd counsel people to be patient a bit first. Sometimes a second edit and/or comment will re-bump it to the top of Active so people will re-visit it.